# Can Alexa understand alpha numeric values such as X001, A1234 etc.? If yes then how to implement this?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a skill that will be able to load a CSV file stored in the S3 bucket and perform certain operations on the file. Everything else is in place except for one very import thing for my use case. The files can have columns with alphanumeric names such as X001, A1234 etc. and I can't figure out a way to make Alexa understand the alphanumeric string. Everytime it recognises the numeric part as the value with both Amazon.SearchQuery as well as my custom slot type.

Is there a way for me to make Alexa understand these type of values?

Answer (score 0):

**Abbreviations and numbers in Slot values**

When you are dealing with abbreviations like `ABC` or alphanumeric like `X001` you have to give sample slot values like this. (try to give more variations)

```
For Abbrevations
x. y. z.
a. b. c.

For alphanumeric
x. zero zero one
y. two three eight
```

**Give a wide variety of samples** and always validate your slot values in your backend.

When testing it in Test Simulator use utterances like

```
the code is x. zero zero one
```

You will get the value of slot as `X001`. A sample request generated by Alexa would be like:

```
"intent": {
            "name": "SomeIntent",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
            "slots": {
                "alphanumericSlot": {
                    "name": "alphanumericSlot",
                    "value": "X001",

...
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Was aware about how to get abbreviations but not about the alphanumeric sample for custom slot values. Will try and let you know if it worked.